# How to report total and complete results

Tags: reporting, partial-effect

I have conducted a social research with one thousand complete participations and more than 1200 total participations (incomplete contributions included).

In reporting the results, what is the best strategy?

1. Reporting statistics of complete participations and referring to statistics of the total number of respondents in the cases in which statistical values for some measures differ from 1% onward.
2. The opposite: reporting statistics about all participations and referring to statistics of complete answers in the cases in which statistical values for some measures differ from 1% onward.
3. Other possible solutions which can be preferred to the previous ones.

Could you motivate your answer, please?